# Creating file that has the same name as a directory where the file is placed

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am using some script that converts one file format **A** into another **B** with a given name. I would like to write a script that is going to attribute to file B a name of directory where A is placed.

ex. If **A** is placed in a directory **1**, after producing file **B** this file is going to have name **1**.

I was reading a little bit about basename command but I am not even sure that I am on good track.

Thank you in advance.
Stefan

N.B. Can anyone of you could suggest me good practical tutorial concerning UNIX, scripts, BASH that could help me progress in this domain?

Answer (score 0):

If your script was working with absolute path:

```
kent$  basename $(dirname /tmp/test/A)
test
```

If it is current path:

```
# we are in /tmp/test
kent$  basename $(pwd)
test
```

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't fully understand what am I ought to do. This is a command that launch script (written in Perl) I am using.   Should I modify actual script or create a new one?                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                  
 #! /bin/sh
perl ~/bin/[script_name] $1 $2
#rm -f A
mv B ~/temp

Comment: what I was writing in the answer is just help you get the target filename of "B", which is `test` in the example. How to do the "convert A->B" logic, I have no idea.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. One more question. I have just seen that script already contains two arguments chosen by user $1 and $2. The second of which is exactly choosing a name of file. Can I therefore erase $2 and place your command preceded by $ to say that second argument (name of output) will always be name of the directory ?

Comment: @user406046 you can try it out, for example, replace the `[script_name]` by `cp` command, and do some test. I don't know if your `$1` (source file) is in absolutepath format or what. You have to check that, and get the correct dir name.

Comment: Hello, 
I have been doing some test and I didn't succeded yet. The thing is the following:
1) first argument of my script $1 is a file on which operations should occur which is in the same folder as a script.
2) second argument of a script $2 is only a name of a file obtained after executing my script. 

In other words I failed to assign to $1 and $2 a file on which operation should occur and name of the output respectively. How can I attribute to $1 and $2 some fixed values? Invoking my script: script a b means operating on a (which is in current folder) to give a output that has name b.